# Update foreground service notification with sensor data

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

I am developing a pedometer. I have a service which is running fine. I made my service foreground also. But how do I update my notification with sensor data. I am getting steps from sensor. I just want to show it in a notification which is showing usig the foreground service.

```
     public class StepCounterService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    public static Boolean FLAG = false;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private StepDetector detector;

    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        startServiceForeground(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d("zzz", "start command");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        new StepCountManager(this);

        FLAG = true;

        Log.e("Service_Started", "");
        detector = new StepDetector(this);


        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(detector,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "S");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        reloadSettings();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        FLAG = false;
        if (detector != null) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(detector);
        }

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }

        Log.e("Service_destroyed", "");
    }

    public void reloadSettings() {

        if (detector != null) {
            detector.setSensitivity(
                    Float.valueOf("10")
            );
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        //Restart the service once it has been killed android


        ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE))
                .set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent
                        .getService(this, 3, new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class), 0));


    }

    public int startServiceForeground(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Mobiefit Walk")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(300, notification);
        Notification n;

        startForeground(300, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


}
```

I just want to show my steps under this notification which I am getting from sensor.

Here is my step_detector class:

```
public class StepDetector implements SensorEventListener {


    public static UpdateStepCount mStepsUpdater;


    public static int CURRENT_SETP = 0;

    public static float SENSITIVITY = 0;   //SENSITIVITY

    private float mLastValues[] = new float[3 * 2];
    private float mScale[] = new float[2];
    private float mYOffset;
    private static long end = 0;
    private static long start = 0;
    private float   mLimit = 10;


    private float mLastDirections[] = new float[3 * 2];
    private float mLastExtremes[][] = { new float[3 * 2], new float[3 * 2] };
    private float mLastDiff[] = new float[3 * 2];
    private int mLastMatch = -1;


    public StepDetector(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        int h = 480;
        mYOffset = h * 0.5f;
        mScale[0] = -(h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2)));
        mScale[1] = -(h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX)));

    }
    public void setSensitivity(float sensitivity) {
        mLimit = sensitivity; // 1.97  2.96  4.44  6.66  10.00  15.00  22.50  33.75  50.62
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
         Log.d("AAA", "Sensor changed");




        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        // Log.i(Constant.STEP_DETECTOR, "onSensorChanged");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            } else {
                int j = (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) ? 1 : 0;
                if (j == 1) {
                    float vSum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        final float v = mYOffset + event.values[i] * mScale[j];
                        vSum += v;
                    }
                    int k = 0;
                    float v = vSum / 3;

                    float direction = (v > mLastValues[k] ? 1: (v < mLastValues[k] ? -1 : 0));
                    if (direction == -mLastDirections[k]) {
                        // Direction changed
                        int extType = (direction > 0 ? 0 : 1); // minimum or
                        // maximum?
                        mLastExtremes[extType][k] = mLastValues[k];
                        float diff = Math.abs(mLastExtremes[extType][k]- mLastExtremes[1 - extType][k]);

                        if (diff > mLimit) {
                            boolean isAlmostAsLargeAsPrevious = diff > (mLastDiff[k] * 2 / 3);
                            boolean isPreviousLargeEnough = mLastDiff[k] > (diff / 3);
                            boolean isNotContra = (mLastMatch != 1 - extType);

                            if (isAlmostAsLargeAsPrevious && isPreviousLargeEnough && isNotContra) {
                                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                if (end - start > 500) {
                                    Log.i("Step_Detector", "CURRENT_SETP:"
                                            + CURRENT_SETP);
                                    CURRENT_SETP++;
                                    mLastMatch = extType;
                                    start = end;
                                }
                            } else {
                                mLastMatch = -1;
                            }
                        }
                        mLastDiff[k] = diff;
                    }
                    mLastDirections[k] = direction;
                    mLastValues[k] = v;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("sensorSteps", String.valueOf(CURRENT_SETP));
        if(mStepsUpdater!=null){
            mStepsUpdater.UpdateStepCount(CURRENT_SETP);
        }



    }




    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static void callBackInit(StepCountManager stepCountManager) {
        mStepsUpdater=  stepCountManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to attach your service with an ongoing Notification, this way your service will be always running. But you still have to manage the 'Force Stop' scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your service running even if the app is killed, make sure to return START_STICKY in `onStartCommand()` as follows :

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // restart service every hour to get the current step count
        ((AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE))
                .set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
                        PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 2,
                                new Intent(this, SensorListener.class),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a Foreground Service.
This is my music player Foreground service code.

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";
String audioPath;
boolean audioPlayed = false;
MediaPlayer mp;
Thread backgroundThread;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.shapeofyou);
    mp.setLooping(true);

    backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            playMusic();
        }
    });

}

private void playMusic() {
    mp.start();
    audioPlayed = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//        audioPath = intent.getStringExtra("path");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Already playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                backgroundThread.start();
            }
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
            PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    previousIntent, 0);

            Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    playIntent, 0);

            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    nextIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Music Player")
                    .setTicker("Music Player")
                    .setContentText("My Music")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,
                            "Stop", ppreviousIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                            pplayIntent).build();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    notification);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.release();
            }
            backgroundThread = null;
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            if (audioPlayed) {
                mp.pause();
                audioPlayed = false;
            } else {
                mp.start();
                audioPlayed = true;
            }
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.release();
            }
            backgroundThread = null;
        }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Used only in case of bound services.
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return START_STICKY;
```

to automatically restart the service when it gets killed for some reasons like low memory.

Comment: you can than try using a foreground notification. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11690802/6904440) might help you.