# Foreground Service Not Updating Sensors Data In Background

Tags: kotlin, android-service, accelerometer, android-sensors, foreground-service

I am new in Android Development, I've created an application with `API version 29` using Kotlin. My main activity is launching a Foreground Service which is doing the following tasks.

- Getting Location using the [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient).
- Getting Sensor Data (Accelerometer and Gyroscope)
- Showing the above information in a Notification

The application is supposed to get the Location and Sensors information in the background and update the Notification.

The Application is currently updating the Sensors and Location data when the Main Activity application is running. Once the Main Activity is closed, the Location data gets updated in the Notification but the Sensor data is not being updated. I've read some QnA sessions (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366795/update-foreground-service-notification-with-sensor-data)) but I'm unable to figure out the issue.

**Code To Launch Service:**

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(this, MyBackgroundService::class.java);
serviceIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
```

**Permissions & Features in Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true" />
```

**Foreground Service in Manifest:**

```
<service android:name=".MyBackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:process=":MyBackgroundServiceProcess"/>
```

I am wondering if there is any `foregroundServiceType` to continuously get the Sensor values when the Main Activity is closed.

Comment: have you got any solution? facing same problem

Comment: Not yet, I moved to another project, I will soon work on this application again.